# How to use the JLocationClient Interface to set mock locations?

Tags: android, delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-xe5, location-client

I'm wanting to make a location simulator to test other application which I'm doing. My intention is to load a KML file (coordinate points) in a list and go through each of these points to test another application that I'm doing.

There are some apps on Play that say to do it, but they don't, they are buggy, so I decided myself for hands-on, to be able to learn, but I ran into a problem.

There is a unit called "Androidapi.JNI.PlayServices.pas" containing several interfaces. One of these interfaces is called "JLocationClient" and I've researched that there is a Java class named "LocationClient" which is responsible for doing exactly what I want, i.e. use and set Mock Locations by setting coordinates (latitude and longitude).

Does anyone know how to use these interfaces? Or know how to get what I want to do without using them? I'm developing a simple Firemonkey project with only one form. This is the start point.